# S3 object returns octet-stream but was uploaded as png

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this existing piece of code that is used to upload files to my s3 bucket.

```py
def get_user_upload_url(customer_id, filename, content_type):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    object_name = "userfiles/uploads/{}/{}".format(customer_id, filename)
    try:
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': BUCKET,
                                                            'Key': object_name,
                                                            "ContentType": content_type # set to "image/png"
                                                            },
                                                    ExpiresIn=100)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    return url
```

This returns to my client a presigned URL that I use to upload my files without a issue. I have added a new use of it where I'm uploading a png and I have behave test that uploads to the presigned url just fine. The problem is if i go look at the file in s3 i cant preview it. If I download it, it wont open either. The s3 web client shows it has Content-Type image/png. I visual compared the binary of the original file and the downloaded file and i can see differences. A file type tool detects that its is an octet-stream.

```py
    signature_file_name = "signature.png"
    with open("features/steps/{}".format(signature_file_name), 'rb') as f:
        files = {'file': (signature_file_name, f)}
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "image/png" # without this or with a different value the presigned url will error with a signatureDoesNotMatch
        }
        context.upload_signature_response = requests.put(response, files=files, headers=headers)
```

I would have expected to have been returned a PNG instead of an octet stream however I'm not sure what I have done wrong . Googling this generally results in people having a problem with the signature because there not properly setting or passing the content type and I feel like I've effectively done that here proven by the fact that if I change the content type everything fails . I'm guessing that there's something wrong with the way I'm uploading the file or maybe reading the file for the upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is todo with how im uploading. So instead it works if i upload like this.

```
context.upload_signature_response = requests.put(response, data=open("features/steps/{}".format(signature_file_name), 'rb'), headers=headers)
```

So this must have to do with the use of put_object. It must be expecting the body to be the file of the defined content type. This method accomplishes that where the prior one would make it a multi part upload. So I think it's safe to say the multipart upload is not compatible with a presigned URL for put_object.

Im still piecing it altogether, so feel free to fill in the blanks.